# Appending News API

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api

I'm having a few issues appending a News API into my HTML. It has worked previously for me using the Guardian API, however, the one I'm trying to add now has images in it.

HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="politics">
        <h3>POLITICS</h3>
        <p id="politics_news"></p>
      </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
  $.ajax( 
  {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      cache: false,
      url: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=XXXXXX",
      success: function(data) 
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
          $("#politics_news").append("<div class='cnn'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.response.results[i].url + "'>" + data.response.results[i].title + " | "  + "</a></div>");
          $("#politics_news").append("<img class='cnn_img'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.response.results[i].urlToImage "</a></img>");
          $("#politics_news").append("<br />");
        }
        console.log(data);
      }
  })
});
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific [when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far with code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: There is nothing being appended to the HTML, just a blank section on the webpage, where I had hoped there would be information.

Comment: Which API are you exactly using now ? Are you sure of the format of your response object ? All this should be in the API doc. Also, make sure to add a src to your image.